# Animation Thread and EDT

Tags: java, swing, applet, thread-safety, event-dispatch-thread

As I discussed with Inerdia on the [earlier post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7863247/how-do-i-know-if-im-on-the-event-dispatch-thread),
something is still strange When I'm  in some JPanel (EDT for sure-I checked with the method check) and then I call some animation thread(the thread extend Thread) to start, inside the thread I'm not on EDT by check.
So I guess I should be because animation should be on EDT, so I wrapped the animate method with runnable and invokeAndWait(), but still got that in the animation thread I'm not on EDT, while calling to that code as I said earlier is on EDT, so, my invokeLater seems not to place that animation on EDT? why is that?

Relevant code(before wrapping the animate method with runnable and passing to invoke later:
So, being on a JPanel there is a line:

```
Animate(trainRailRoadTrack);
```

Implementation is:

```
void Animate(ArrayList<RailroadSquare> i_TrainRailRoadTrack) {
    ArrayList<JPanelRailoadSquare> playerRailoadPanelsTrack = getRelevantRailroads(i_TrainRailRoadTrack);
    new SuspendedAnimation(playerRailoadPanelsTrack).start();
    jPanelBoard1.GetGameManager().EmptyPlayerSolution();
}

private class SuspendedAnimation extends Thread
{
    private ArrayList<JPanelRailoadSquare> m_PlayerRailoadPanelsTrack;

    public SuspendedAnimation(ArrayList<JPanelRailoadSquare> i_PlayerRailoadPanelTrack)
    {
        m_PlayerRailoadPanelsTrack = i_PlayerRailoadPanelTrack;
    }

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
       m_IsAnimationNeeded = true;
       for (JPanelRailoadSquare currRailoadSquare: m_PlayerRailoadPanelsTrack)
       {
           System.out.println("Is on Event dispatch thread: "+SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread());
           currRailoadSquare.SetGoingTrain();
           repaint();                            
           try
           {
               Thread.sleep(150);

           }
           catch (InterruptedException e){}
           currRailoadSquare.UnSetGoingTrain();
           repaint();                       
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside of `SuspendedAnimation.run()` you're *not* on the EDT. That's where you need to use `invokeLater()`, not when calling `Animate()`:

```
@Override
public void run()
{
    // We're outside the EDT in most of run()
    m_IsAnimationNeeded = true;
    for (JPanelRailoadSquare currRailoadSquare: m_PlayerRailoadPanelsTrack)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {
            // The code that "talks" to Swing components has to be put on
            // the EDT
            currRailoadSquare.SetGoingTrain();
            repaint();
        });

        // We want to keep sleeping outside the EDT.
        try
        {
            Thread.sleep(150);
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e){}

        SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {
            currRailoadSquare.UnSetGoingTrain();
            repaint();                       
        }
    }
}
```