# How does one guarantee that an ScheduledExecutorService is running on the EDT?

Tags: java, swing, thread-safety

While working on the animation and updating timer for a game, I read that any activities relating to the GUI should be run on the EDT, including repainting the screen. I am using a single `ScheduledExecutorService` to update and draw the game (using active rendering). The initial schedule to the service (which is a nested class that `implements Runnable`) is done in a call like this:

```
ScheduledExecutorService ex = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            ex.schedule(new UpdatingService(), 1, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        }
    });
```

I thought that this would make the service run on the EDT but adding `System.out.println(SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread());` proved that it was not.

I did some searching and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7867960/animation-thread-and-edt) post that mentioned starting the EDT *inside* the timer. I tried this and it does work. However, it doesn't seem like a good idea to nest Threads like that.

So, is nesting Threads like this not as bad as it seems? And if it is a bad idea, then what would be the proper way to ensure that a `ScheduledExecutorService` is running on the EDT?

Comment: "*I did some searching and found this post that mentioned starting the EDT inside the timer.*" => That's the way to go.

Comment: The easiest way to ensure your code executes on the event dispatch thread is to use [javax.swing.Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html) (not java.util.Timer) instead of a ScheduledExecutorService.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your code:

```
ScheduledExecutorService ex = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            ex.schedule(new UpdatingService(), 1, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        }
    });
```

The only code executed on the EDT here is the `ex.schedule` invocation. The code that is then invoked by the scheduler later, eg `new UpdatingService()` will run on the thread that is internal to the scheduler, which will not be the EDT but some thread created by the call to `Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor`

Perhaps what I would do is have your scheduler schedule an update method (your updating service perhaps), which itself then puts a call onto the EDT via invokeLater.

Eg, something like:

```
ScheduledExecutorService ex = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
ex.schedule(new Updater(), 1, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
...
class Updater extends Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
      // invoke the EDT via Swing Utilities here.     
    }
}
```

This is my best advice without seeing what the rest of your code is doing.