# GUI components don't load when another method is loaded

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I am working on a game that uses a custom console-style GUI to play. I previously asked a question to find out what was causing a NullPointerException. See [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32210711/nullpointerexception-when-trying-to-use-method-from-custom-jpanel) for context.

I now have the error eliminated, but I have a new issue: When I start the game, the GUI only loads the JFrame (EDIT: JPanel not JFrame) but none of the other components. In the original post, the GUI components loaded up normally, but starting the game itself would cause a NullPointerException due to a call to the JTextArea before the GUI dispatch thread was complete.

Here is the current code:

Classic.java

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.*;
import static javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater;
public class Classic extends Game{
    private static JFrame gui;
    private static GUIClassic newContentPane;
    ...
    public void play() {
        invokeLater(Classic::startGUI);
        invokeLater(Classic::startGame);
    }
    public static void startGame() {
        //Game processes
    ...
    }
    private static void startGUI() {
        gui = new JFrame("Karma :: Classic Mode");
        gui.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        newContentPane = new GUIClassic();
        newContentPane.setOpaque(true);
        gui.setContentPane(newContentPane);
        gui.pack();
        gui.setVisible(true);
    }
    ...
}
```

GUIClassic.java

```
...
public class GUIClassic extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
    private JTextArea output;
    private JTextField input;
    private boolean inputReady;
    private String inputText;
    public GUIClassic() {
        super();
        setLayout(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
        output = new JTextArea(15, 15);
        output.setEditable(false);
        JScrollPane outputScroll = new JScrollPane(output);
        input = new JTextField("",40);
        add(outputScroll);
        add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(0,5)));
        add(input);
    }
}
```

In the `play()` method of Classic.java, I tried removing the `invokeLater(...)` methods, that came up with the same result.

```
public void play() {
    startGUI();
    startGame();
}
```

I also tried moving the call to `startGame` within `startGUI`:

```
public static void startGUI() {
    ...
    startGame();
}
```

However, removing `startGame` altogether allows it to start up normally:

```
public void play() {
    invokeLater(Classic::startGUI);
}
```

I am completely at a loss. I don't understand why loading the GUI without playing the game loads it fine, but beginning the game suddenly makes the components disappear.

Please note: there are no exceptions thrown during runtime.

As a side note, the GUI also does not allow me to close it via the [X] button in the current version, but in the cases where only 'startGUI' is called, the components pop up and the [X] allows you to exit.

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: You don't show us the content of startGame(), so we can't tell what you are doing in that method that will cause the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to invoke the `startGame()` in a new Thread, because all of the painting stuff is done in the main-thread like that

```
  new Thread(new Runnable() {

     @Override
     public void run() {
        Classic.startGame();
     }
  }).start();
```

Comment: I have learned in the last two days that I really need to learn how Threading works. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You never set the size of your Panel.
Try to use the `setPreferredSize(Dimension)`-method of your GUIClassic before you call the `pack()`-method of your JFrame.

Comment: All it does is change the size. It does not make the components show up. I just tried it. However, it does show that it's a problem with the JPanel, so I will amend that in the post.

Comment: Also, the GUI components load when `startGame` is not called. If that method is called, then the components don't load.