# My JLabel don't refresh quickly. Why?

Tags: java, jlabel, java-threads

I'm reading a media with vlcj and I would like to display the time elapsed and the remaining time in some JLabels. I wrote some code but it seems my JLabel.setText don't refresh more that 2 times per second.

To make some more try and being sure that it's not the vlcj's thread that would have some troubles, I wrote a very code with a JLabel. The aim of this simple code is to update the JLabel 10 times per seconds.

Here is my code :

```
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class TestLabel extends JFrame implements Runnable{
JLabel label = new JLabel("0");
int i=0;
TestLabel() {
    this.setTitle("Test");
    this.setSize(200, 200);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setContentPane(label);
    this.setVisible(true);      
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    TestLabel tLabel = new TestLabel();
    Thread t1 = new Thread(tLabel);
    t1.start();
}

@Override
public void run() {
    ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
    scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            i+=1;
            System.out.println(i);
            label.setText(String.valueOf(i));               
        }           
    }, 0, 100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);      
}
}
```

Result : in the console, I get 1, 2, 3, 4... But in the JLabel, I have something like : 1, 2, 3 (...) 32, 37, 42, 47. It seems that the System.out.println write each "i", but the JLabel don't. Why do I have this artefact ?

Thank you for all your reply. Regards.

Answer (score 2):

You need to call the `SwingUtilities.invokeLater` method to properly update your GUI text while using Swing (i.e. `JFrame`, `JLabel`, etc).

```
public void run() {
    i+=1;
    System.out.println(i);
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            label.setText(String.valueOf(i));               
        }           
    }); 
}
```

For more information about SwingUtilities.invokeLater, check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12077245/what-is-swingutilities-invokelater) SO post.

Answer (score 2):

Thou shalt not use swing components from a thread other than the event dispatch thread.

So, either use a [Swing Timer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html) rather than a ScheduledExecutorService, or wrap the label change into `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()`.

BTW, the call to `new TestLabel();` should also be wrapped into `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()`. Read the [swing concurrency tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html).

Comment: Voteup for the English lesson

Answer (score 1):

Don't use a ScheduledExecutorService. Swing components need to be updated on the `Event Dispatch Thread (EDT)`.

Instead you should be using a `Swing Timer`. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for more information.

Here is a simple example using a Timer: [How to make JScrollPane (In BorderLayout, containing JPanel) smoothly autoscroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33907207/how-to-make-jscrollpane-in-borderlayout-containing-jpanel-smoothly-autoscroll/33907282#33907282). Just change the interval to 100, instead of 1000.