# Command Line in Java Outputs

Tags: java, command-line, cmd, command-prompt

I have successfully made it so when a user clicks a button, a command line statement runs and they are able to see the output of it.

However, they are only able to see the output of it once the command has finished.

I was intending on the user seeing a real time output like they would if they were using the command prompt in windows.

Could I get some guidance as to how to do this?

Code:

```
Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
                try 
                {
                    process = runtime.exec("ping riot.de");
                } 
                catch (IOException e1)
                {
                    System.err.print("Error: " + e1);
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
                try 
                {
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
                    String line;
                    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
                    {
                        sb.append(line);
                        sb.append("\n");
                    }
                    run.setText(sb.toString());
                } 
                catch (IOException e) 
                {
                    System.err.println("Error: " + e);
                }
```

EDIT - Made new thread and trying to use SwingUtilities.invokeLater
This allows you to see the frames components while its working, however it still doesnt write to the textarea line by line.

```
Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
                try 
                {
                    process = runtime.exec("ping riot.de");
                } 
                catch (IOException e1)
                {
                    System.err.print("Error: " + e1);
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
            {
                @Override
                public void run()
                {
                    try 
                    {
                        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
                        String line;
                        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
                        {
                            sb.append(line);
                            sb.append("\n");
                            run.setText(sb.toString());
                        }
                    } 
                    catch (IOException e) 
                    {
                        System.err.println("Error: " + e);
                    }
                }
            });
```

Comment: What is the type of the `run` variable, in `run.setText(sb.toString());`?

Comment: How about putting `run.setText(sb.toString());` inside your while loop?

Comment: @jrahhali It's a JTextArea

Comment: @Plirkee I'm afraid that changed nothing

Comment: You'll need a separate thread to accept command output and append it to the text box via `SwingUtilities.invokeLater`.

Comment: I agree with @MarkoTopolnik you definitely need to run this code snippet on a different thread.

Answer (score 0):

Swing uses Single-threaded model so you reading blocks GUI thread and no event is dispatched and no text rendered until it is free.

You should create a new thread and put all the reading there and update JTextArea text within the loop using SwingUtilities.invokeLater.

You could also use SwingWorker.

Comment: I will try and do this and get back to you. - I haven't dealt with threads in Java/Swing yet so this could take a while

Comment: Could you let me know if I'm doing this correctly in my edit?

Comment: You should call thread.start() and wrap run.setText(sb.toString()); into SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()  { ...  }); See example here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12077245/what-is-swingutilities-invokelater