# Working on a java based chatting application using threading

Tags: java, multithreading

I was trying to send message through threading. dataAvailable is a variable which tells whether message is available on textfield or not. if available dataAvailable is set to true and in run() method if it is true following code is executed. But the problem is in run() it never sees dataAvailable is true and nothing is sent. Help needed.

This is client

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class PeerOne extends JFrame implements Runnable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    JTextField outgoing;
    JTextArea incoming;
    JButton send;
    Thread t,t1;
    ObjectOutputStream output;  //for writing objects to a stream
    ObjectInputStream input;    //for reading objects from a stream
    Socket s;
    volatile boolean dataAvailable=false;
    String message = null;
    public PeerOne()
    {
        outgoing = new JTextField();
        outgoing.setEnabled(true);
        outgoing.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if(!(e.getActionCommand().isEmpty()))
                {
                    dataAvailable = true;
                    System.out.print("hi");
                }
            }
        });

        this.add(outgoing,BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        incoming = new JTextArea();
        incoming.setEditable(true);
        this.add(new JScrollPane(incoming),BorderLayout.CENTER);
        this.add(incoming);

        setSize(300,150);
        setVisible(true);

        try
        {
            s = new Socket("localhost",5500);
            incoming.append("Connection Successfull..."+"\n");

            output = new ObjectOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
            output.flush();
            input = new ObjectInputStream(s.getInputStream());

        }
        catch (UnknownHostException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        t = new Thread(this,"PeerOne");
        System.out.print("New Thread");
        //t1 = new Thread(this,"Two");
        t.start();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        new PeerOne();
    }

    public void run()
    {   
        while(true)
        {
            if(dataAvailable==true)
            {
                try 
                {
                    System.out.print(0);
                    output.writeObject(outgoing.getText());
                    output.flush();
                    dataAvailable = false;
                }
                catch (IOException e1) 
                {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            try 
            {
                try 
                {
                    message = (String)input.readObject();

                    incoming.append(message);
                }
                catch (ClassNotFoundException e) 
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }       
        }

    }
}
```

This is server

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class PeerTwo extends JFrame implements Runnable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    JTextField outgoing;
    JTextArea incoming;
    JButton send;
    Thread t;
    Socket s;   
    ObjectOutputStream output;  //for writing objects to a stream
    ObjectInputStream input;    //for reading objects from a stream
    volatile boolean dataAvailable=false;
    String message = null;

    public PeerTwo()
    {
        outgoing = new JTextField();
        outgoing.setEnabled(true);
        outgoing.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if(!(e.getActionCommand().isEmpty()))
                {
                    dataAvailable = true;
                }
            }
        });

        this.add(outgoing,BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        incoming = new JTextArea();
        incoming.setEditable(true);
        this.add(new JScrollPane(incoming),BorderLayout.CENTER);
        this.add(incoming);

        setSize(300,150);
        setVisible(true);
        try
        {
            ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(5500,100);
            s = ss.accept();

            output = new ObjectOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
            output.flush();
            input = new ObjectInputStream(s.getInputStream());
        }
        catch (UnknownHostException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        t = new Thread(this,"PeerTwo");
        System.out.print("New Thread");
        t.start();



    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new PeerTwo();
    }

    public void run() 
    {
            while(true)
            {
                if(dataAvailable==true)
                {
                    try 
                    {
                        System.out.print("bbb");
                        output.writeObject(outgoing.getText());
                        output.flush();
                        dataAvailable = false;
                    }
                    catch (IOException e1) 
                    {
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                try {
                        try 
                        {
                            message = (String)input.readObject();
                            System.out.print(0);
                            incoming.append(message);
                        }
                        catch (ClassNotFoundException e) 
                        {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }       
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: You have two dataAvailable variables which are in different classes and therefore aren't shared; setting one does not set the other.

Comment: dataAvailable is used restrict to write to output stream but code to read message is free from any conditional statement.When dataAvailable is true in PeerOne, run() should be able to read dataAvailable as true and send the msg but it isn't and if i write condition as dataAvailable==false it sends msg

Comment: Didn't you try to ask this same question yesterday, under a different account?

Comment: You have two dataAvailable variables.

Answer (score 3):

This code has several bugs/issues:

1. Endless loop. Your code  wastes processor time. I would recommend use [guarded block](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/guardmeth.html) for write procedure or at least sleep.
2. Read is blocked. Code doesn't have any checking from input stream.
3. Working with swing components outside [EDT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7217013/java-event-dispatching-thread-explanation)
4. Application still works when you close application window. (use this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);)

So i would like to suggest *hotfix*. It will make your code work.
PeerOne(client):

```
public void run() {
        while (true) {
            if (dataAvailable == true) {
                try {
                    System.out.print(0);
                    output.writeUTF(outgoing.getText());
                    output.flush();
                    dataAvailable = false;
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            try {
                if (input.available() > 0) {
                    message = input.readUTF();
                    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            incoming.append(message);
                            incoming.append("\n");
                        }
                    });
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(300);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

PeerTwo(server):

```
public void run() {
    while (true) {
        if (dataAvailable == true) {
            try {
                System.out.print("bbb");
                output.writeUTF(outgoing.getText());
                output.flush();
                dataAvailable = false;
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        try {
            if (input.available() > 0) {
                message = input.readUTF();
                System.out.print(0);
                SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        incoming.append(message);
                        incoming.append("\n");
                    }
                });
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(300);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

So as you can i fixed 1-3 problems and used readUTF/writeUTF instead readObject/writeObject to simplify code. The next step is split reading/writing to 2 single threads. You can do it on your own.

Comment: Wasn't going to apply for production but suggestions are welcomed. Nicely pointed out the issues one by one.