# Background image in java swing issue

Tags: java, image, swing, user-interface, paintcomponent

I've made a Jpanel with a background image and a Jbutton also with its background. The problem is that background sometimes is loaded sometimes no.

```
public class Window extends JFrame {

    public static JFrame createwindow() {//fare singleton
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Battaglia navale");

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(740, 740);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setResizable( false );

        Dimension dim = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();

        frame.setLocation(((int)dim.getWidth()-(int)frame.getWidth())/2, ((int)dim.getHeight()-(int)frame.getHeight())/2);

        return frame;
    }
}

public class StartWindow {

    JFrame frame;
    private JButton button;
    private JButton button2;
    final String button_start = "img/start.png";
    ImageIcon start = new ImageIcon(button_start);

    public void CreateStartWindow() {
        frame = Window.createwindow();
        Container container = frame.getContentPane();
        JpanelStart panel = new JpanelStart();
        container.add(panel);

        this.button = new JButton(start);
        button.setActionCommand("start");
        button.setHideActionText(true);
        button.setOpaque(false);
        button.setFocusPainted(false);
        button.setBorderPainted(false);
        button.setContentAreaFilled(false);

        this.button2 = new JButton("Classifica");

        panel.add(button);
        panel.add(button2);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void addActionListener(ActionListener al) {
        this.button.addActionListener(al);
        this.button2.addActionListener(al);
    }

    public void chiudi() {
        frame.dispose();
    }
}

class JpanelStart extends JPanel {

    private Image img;
    private String path_img = "img/sfondo.jpg";

    public JpanelStart() {
        img = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage(path_img);
        loadImage(img);
    }

    private void loadImage(Image img) {
        try {
            MediaTracker track = new MediaTracker(this);
            track.addImage(img, 0);
            track.waitForID(0);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        setOpaque(false);
        g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, this);
        super.paintComponent(g);

    }
}
```

Comment: Draw the image after `super.paintComponent(g);`

Comment: Done but doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `super.paintComponet` should go right after the method signature.
2. you set the `button` opacity to false, so it won't be seen.
3. Run your program from the Event Dispatch Thread.

   ```
   public static void main(String[] args){
       SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
           public void run() {
               new StartWindow().CreateStartWindow();  
           }
       });
   }
   ```
4. In your method, you're making the frame visible before adding anything. Leave that out in the method
5. Don't set the size of the frame. Instead override the `getPrefereedSize()` of the `JPanel` and call `pack()` on the frame.
6. IMO, I see no use *at all* for this so-called helper method. I would toss it out the window
7. You should load your image as an embedded resource, and not from the file system.

   ```
   img = ImageIO.read(StartWindow.class.getResource(path_img));
   ```

---

```
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.MediaTracker;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class StartWindow {

    JFrame frame;
    private JButton button;
    private JButton button2;
    final String button_start = "img/start.png";
    ImageIcon start = new ImageIcon(button_start);

    public void CreateStartWindow() throws IOException  {
        frame = Window.createwindow();
        Container container = frame.getContentPane();
        JpanelStart panel = new JpanelStart();
        container.add(panel);

        this.button = new JButton(start);
        button.setActionCommand("start");
        button.setHideActionText(true);
        button.setOpaque(false);
        button.setFocusPainted(false);
        button.setBorderPainted(false);
        button.setContentAreaFilled(false);

        this.button2 = new JButton("Classifica");

        panel.add(button);
        panel.add(button2);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);


    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
            public void run() {
                try {
                    new StartWindow().CreateStartWindow();
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(StartWindow.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }
        });

    }

    public void addActionListener(ActionListener al) {
        this.button.addActionListener(al);
        this.button2.addActionListener(al);
    }

    public void chiudi() {
        frame.dispose();
    }
}

class Window {

    public static JFrame createwindow() {//fare singleton

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Battaglia navale");

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        frame.setResizable(false);
        Dimension dim = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();

        return frame;

    }

}



class JpanelStart extends JPanel {
    private static final int D_W = 700;
    private static final int D_H = 700;

    private Image img;
    private String path_img = "/images/logo.gif";

    public JpanelStart() throws IOException {

        img = ImageIO.read(StartWindow.class.getResource(path_img));
        loadImage(img);

    }

    private void loadImage(Image img) {
        try {
            MediaTracker track = new MediaTracker(this);
            track.addImage(img, 0);
            track.waitForID(0);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, D_W, D_W, this);
    }

    @Override 
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(D_W, D_H);
    }
}
```

---

**Shows Up Every time **

[image]

Answer (score 2):

- draw the image after `super.paintComponent(g)` (which draws the component that you want to draw on top of)
- call `repaint()` in `loadImage()` after the image is set (so that it redraws it)
- `loadImage()` doesn't seem to be setting the `img` variable does it need to?
- (not essential but recommended) you should also move UI changes into the [EDT (Event Dispatch Thread)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7217013/java-event-dispatching-thread-explanation).

**Example of running a UI task on EDT**

This puts UI operations on a queue so that all UI changes are made from the same thread and avoid interference.

```
java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        //UI Operations
    }
} );
```

Comment: I've added an example and another point to my list regarding `img` never being set after creation of `JpanelStart`