# Can an event in one class trigger an action in another class?

Tags: java, swing, events, event-handling, mouseevent

I'm writing a program that completes the following tasks in sequence:

1. Collects user input from a JPanel
2. Uses the input to copy dependencies from the program directory into a new project directory
3. Uses the input to construct an interactive graph in the project directory

I have a separate class for each task and a main class that calls each object in sequence.

My problem is that the main class evaluates step 2 before step 1 is complete. Because the user has not yet closed the JPanel when the main class calls object 2, the user input is not collected before step 2 starts and the program crashes.

What I need is a way to signal to class 2 that the JPanel in class 1 has been closed. This way step 2 begins *after* the input fields have been collected in step 1.

Is there a way to have the window closing in class 1 trigger an action in class 2? If not, what would be the best way to solve this problem?

Comment: You are most likely either 1) running Swing components off of the EDT, causing threading issues or 2) not using a modal dialogue.

Comment: I read up on threading and I think that might be the problem. I was hoping to keep things compartmentalized, but I guess I'll just have to put it all in one class. For anyone else who stumbles across this, the EDT is the Event Dispatch Thread and there's a pretty good article on it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7217013/java-event-dispatching-thread-explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick to communicating events between classes is the `wait()` and `notify()` methods.

Suppose you're executing a `main` method. At some point `main` invokes another class, say a gui. Here you want `main` to pause and *wait* for certain events in the gui to complete before `main` proceeds with the rest of its actions.

This is accomplished by synchronizing code blocks between the two classes and telling `main` to `wait()` until the gui *notifies* it to proceed, `notify()`. For example:

**main**

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    GUI gui = new GUI();

    // Do some things
    doSomething();
    doSomthingElse();

    // Make sure we wait until gui input has been collected before proceeding
    synchronized(gui) {
        try {
            gui.wait();
        }
        catch(InterruptedException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    // Do some things using the gui input we've been waiting for        
    doSomeMoreThings();
}
```

**gui**

```
// The gui method we want to synchronize
public void collectInput() {

    synchronized(this) {

        // Collect fields
        name = nameField.getText();
        age = ageField.getText();
        date = dateField.getText();

        // Notify waiter that our business is complete  
        notify();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

> "Is there a way to have the window closing in class 1 trigger an action in class 2? If not, what would be the best way to solve this problem?"

As Boris the Spider pointed out, you should be using a model dialog. You're probably using a frame. You should read up on [Modality](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/modality-137604.html) to learn its behavior and features. Also take some time to look at [How to make Dialogs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html). In short, turning the dialog's modality on (which is defaulted on [JOptionPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html) static `showXxx` methods and can be set on `JDialog` either through [`setModalityType`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Dialog.html#setModalityType-java.awt.Dialog.ModalityType-) or passed through the [constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JDialog.html#JDialog-java.awt.Dialog-boolean-)), the flow will "block" until the dialog is closed.

Below is an example. It may be overcomplicated for such a simple task (as it could easily be accomplished with a `JOptionPane`), but it shows how to use a `JDialog`. Look as the `ShowDialogActionListener` class. The dialog is set visible and flow is not continued in the actionPerformed until the dialog is closed, which is when the `Input` is obtained from the dialog.

```
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class DialogDemo {
    private JFrame frame = new JFrame();

    public DialogDemo() {
        JButton button = new JButton("Open Dialog");
        button.addActionListener(new ShowDialogActionListener());
        frame.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        frame.add(button);
        frame.setSize(300, 300);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    class ShowDialogActionListener implements ActionListener {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            InputDialog dialog = new InputDialog(frame, true);
            System.out.println("Opened dialog.....");

            long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
            dialog.setVisible(true);
            System.out.println("Dialog closed after "
                    + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start) + " ms");

            Input input = dialog.getInput();
            ServiceOne service = new ServiceOne();
            service.serviceMethod(input);
        }
    }

    class ServiceOne {
        public void serviceMethod(Input input) {
            System.out.println(input.getInput());
        }
    }

    class InputDialog extends JDialog {
        private Input input;

        public InputDialog(JFrame parent, boolean modal) {
            super(parent, modal);

            JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1));
            final JTextField field = new JTextField(20);
            JButton okButton = new JButton("OK");
            panel.add(field);
            panel.add(okButton);

            okButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    String text = field.getText();
                    input = new Input();
                    input.setInput(text);
                    InputDialog.this.dispose();
                }
            });

            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            add(panel);
            setSize(250, 250);
            setLocationRelativeTo(parent);
        }

        public Input getInput() {
            return input;
        }
    }

    class Input {
        private String input = "default";

        public void setInput(String input) {
            this.input = input;
        }

        public String getInput() {
            return input;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new DialogDemo();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

As I said earlier, the same could easily have been accomplished with

```
String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a Message");
```

The above would also block flow execution.

Comment: I think you may have misunderstood my question. I ran the code you provided and it does almost exactly what my program currently does--opens a parent window, opens a pop-up window when a button in the parent window is clicked, and logs the pop-up window input when the pop-up is closed.

What I need is a way to then communicate to a separate class (the class from which the parent window was invoked) that the _parent_ window has been closed. Otherwise the class that invoked the input gui tries to execute the rest of its tasks before the gui input has actually been collected.

Comment: It'll be a lot easier to tell what you're talking about with some code. Please edit your post with some relevant code

Comment: If there was concise way to show you some code, I would have :) But I figured it out--had to use wait() and notify().