# Display info from paintComponent() in textPane

Tags: java, user-interface

I have my GUI:

```
JTextPane numbers;

JFrame frame = new JFrame("GUI");
Numbers nums = new Nums();
numbers = new JTextPane();
frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(0,3));
JPanel p = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0,1));
frame.add(p);
p.add(new JLabel("Phone numbers: "));
numbers.add(nums);
p.add(numbers);
frame.pack();
frame.setVisible(true);
```

Numbers class:

```
public class Numbers extends JLabel implements Timing {

private TimerCallback nos;

public Numbers(){
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 250));
    nos = new TimerCallback(this, 100L);
    nos.start();
}   

@Override
public void tick() {
    repaint();
}

@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    String pn = phoneNumbersMap.toString();
    g.drawString("Phone numbers: \n"+pn, 75, 10);
}

}
```

The problem is that GUI does not display info from paintComponent in numbers TextPane. What can I do to display text there?

Comment: Is the JLabel inside the JTextPane mandatory or would using JTextPane.setText() also be a valid solution?

Comment: It's not mandatory, I just need a way to display that information

Comment: Is your Numbers Panel even showing in the first place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While overriding *paintComponent()* is possible, you should avoid it where possible. Swing is doing a pretty good job when you are using the provided Components as is.

In your case, I would suggest deriving *Numbers* from **JTextPane** instead of *JLabel*. Now, do your *phoneNumbersMap* to *String* magic there and set it via **JTextPane.setText()**.

I suppose your **TimerCallback** is somehow running on a Thread different from [EDT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7217013/java-event-dispatching-thread-explanation/7217304#7217304). In this case, wrap the **setText()** call in **SwingUtilities.invokeLater()** to make sure Swing can repaint it properly.

By the way, you have chosen to use two cascaded *GridLayouts*. Unless this is not caused by you, trying to reduce the example, you might want to take a look at the **BorderLayout**, which I used in GUI below.

I changed your example a bit to be able to execute it and get some output.
Here my code proposal.

GUI:

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame("GUI");
Numbers numbers = new Numbers();
frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
frame.add(new JLabel("Phone numbers: "), BorderLayout.NORTH);
frame.add(numbers,BorderLayout.CENTER);
frame.pack();
frame.setVisible(true);
```

Number:

```
public class Numbers extends JTextPane implements Timing {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String phoneNumbersMap = "Start";

    private TimerCallback nos;

    public Numbers() {
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 250));
        nos = new TimerCallback(this, 100L);
        nos.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void tick() {
        phoneNumbersMap += "Test\n";
        String pn = phoneNumbersMap.toString();
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                Numbers.this.setText("Phone numbers: \n" + pn);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Timing Interface:

```
public interface Timing {

    void tick();

}
```

TimerCallback:

```
public class TimerCallback {

    Timer tim;
    private long period;
    private Numbers numbers;

    public TimerCallback(Numbers numbers, long period) {
        tim = new Timer(true);
        this.period = period;
        this.numbers = numbers;
    }

    public void start() {
        tim.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                TimerCallback.this.numbers.tick();
            }
        }, new Date(), period);
    }

}
```