# Thread.sleep() pauses JFrame before other statements

Tags: java, swing, jframe, event-dispatch-thread

Thread.sleep() always pauses JFrame before the sleep() statement even gets executed.
I have the following method to pause the thread:

```
private void sleep(int milli)   {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(milli);
    }   catch   (InterruptedException ex)   {
        writeToConsoleError("Interrupted");
    }
}
```

I'm calling it in the following switch-case statement under case CARDNOMATCH:, **this method is in a class which extends JFrame.**

```
public void handlePacket(Packet recieved)   {
    int cmd = recieved.getCommand();
    int arg1 = -99;
    int arg2 = -99;
    switch (cmd)    {
        case CARDNOMATCH:
            arg1 = recieved.getFirstArg();
            arg2 = recieved.getSecondArg();
            if(arg1 > 9)    {
                arg1 = 9;
            }
            if(arg2 > 9)    {
                arg2 = 9;
            }
            flipCard(choice1, arg1);
            flipCard(choice2, arg2);
            sleep(3000);
            flipCard(choice1, 10);
            flipCard(choice2, 10);
            break;
        case ENABLE_TURN:
            this.isTurn = true;
            break;
        case DISABLE_TURN:
            this.isTurn = false;
            break;
    }
}
```

Please, anyone, give me some insight :(

Comment: Are you sleeping in the event thread? That'll freeze your GUI, which is not what you want.

Comment: 1) Don't block the EDT (Event Dispatch Thread).  The GUI will 'freeze' when that happens.  See [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for details and the fix. 2) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: @Kayaman yup, its inside a method which is called by actionlistener. How would I still wait 3 seconds without having it in an event?

Comment: Start a `SwingWorker` (which will run in not EDT), have *that* sleep 3 seconds, then perform some action (possibly with `invokeLater()`).

Comment: You want to step back and read about the threading model to be used when dealing with Swing UIs. See the duplicated question; and probably http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7217013/java-event-dispatching-thread-explanation too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UI is not updated instantaneously.

When you call

```
flipCard(choice1, arg1);
flipCard(choice2, arg2);
```

I assume `flipCard` updates the UI in some way. And your expected behaviour is that `choice1` and `choice2` cards will be flipped, wait 3 seconds, and flip them again. But the actual behaviour you get is that nothing happens until 3 seconds have passed, after 3 seconds, the cards flipped twice.

What you need to understand is that UI has a frame rate. When you call `flipCard`, the card will not be flipped until the next frame. During the time between this frame and the next, `Thread.sleep` is called so everything, including the frames, pause for 3 seconds. That's why the UI updated after 3 seconds' pause.

I suggest you to use `javax.swing.Timer` or `javax.swing.SwingWorker`. See [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) or [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html) for more info.